# Routing No hint path defined for [module-name]

Tags: laravel-5

I am using Laravel5.5 and Module package. I have one student module and want to make this as a default for front-end, so committed code of the laravel's default routes/web.php
Here is my student's routes:

```
<?php

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'web', 'namespace' => 'Modules\Student\Http\Controllers'], function() {

        /** Frontend routes which does not require authentication
         *
         */
        Route::get('/', 'FrontEndController@index')->name('frontend.home');
        Route::get('/program-search', 'FrontEndController@programs')->name('student.programs');
        Route::get('/univeristy-search', 'FrontEndController@univerities')->name('student.universities');
    });
```

And here is my controller code:

```
<?php
    namespace Modules\Student\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Modules\Admin\Http\Models\ProgramCategory;
use Modules\University\Http\Models\Program;
use Modules\Student\Http\Models\Student;
use Modules\University\Http\Models\University;

    class FrontEndController extends Controller
    {
        /**
         * Display a listing of the resource.
         * @return Response
         */
        public function index()
        {
            return view('student::index');
        }

        /**
         * Show all programs
         */
        public function programs(){
            $categories = ProgramCategory::orderBy('catagory_name')
                ->where('status', '=', 'active');
            $programs = Program::orderBy('program_name')
                ->where([
                    ['status', '=', 'active']
                ]);
            $programs->categories = $categories;
            return view('student::program_list')
                ->withPrograms( $programs );
        }

        public function univerities()
        {
            return view('student::university_list');
        }
    }
```

only first route '/' is working. when I try to access '/program-search' and '/univeristy-search' it throws an error like `"No hint path defined for [sutdent]. (View: /var/www/development/unigatenew/Modules/Student/Resources/views/university_list.blade.php)"`.

What is the wrong I am doing? can anybody help out this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake was including the same file name inside view. Renaming file name which was included solved the problem.